# Go back two levels with UINavigationController and Storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller

I have a Storyboard with three views A, B and C (and more). From view B, the user can go back to view A by tapping the left button bar item that's automatically created. I've changed the label on this to "Cancel" by setting the Back Button property of A's navigation item.

C should have the same Cancel button, but it doesn't make sense to go back to view B; rather it should jump back to A. I know how to do this programatically but where do I put the code so it's triggered when C's Cancel button is tapped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cancel an action from B or C and go back to A it may make more sense to present the view controllers modally.

From the [iOS human interface guidelines:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html)

> A modal view generally displays a button that completes the task and dismisses the view, and a Cancel button users can tap to abandon the task.
>
> Use a modal view when you need to offer the ability to accomplish a self-contained task related to your application’s primary function. A modal view is especially appropriate for a multistep subtask that requires UI elements that don’t belong in the main application user interface all the time.

Answer (score 9):

I found this way simplest, just put index:

```
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you cannot override the back button function. What I do in those cases, is create a left bar item and on it's function decide which navigationController view to send the user to.

I do that by using:

```
[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Index 1 will be the first view after the root viewController, if A is your rootView, you can also use:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pushing C, use the replace option in the segue so that it will do this automatically for you.

Comment: Sounds promising but I'm not seeing a replace option. A quick Google suggested it might be an iPad-only thing?

Comment: Interesting....  I woul think that it would work for both but I haven't done it on the iPhone before.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: if you put the following into B, it will remove it from the stack when C is presented. Then the stack looks like `[A,C]` so back will go straight to A.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // remove this view controller from the stack
    if let nav = self.navigationController {
        let vcs = nav.viewControllers.filter {(vc) in
            return (vc as? MyViewController) == nil
        }

        self.navigationController?.setViewControllers(vcs, animated: false)
    }
}
```